# Generating every string up to a length

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through every string possible within a set length.

So if the set length is 2, it will iterate through:

a,
b,
c,
d..
y,
z,
aa,
ab,
ac..
ay,
az,
ba,
bb, etc

etc. I've tried searching up some code on it, but I've found nothing. I just want to know the theory behind it. I've tried many different ideas but I just can't wrap my head around on how I should do it.

Edit: The characters I'm doing is just a-z lowercase

Comment: You have to define the universe of characters (letters)

Comment: Have a look at itertool's combinations, permutiations, ...: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Use itertools to generate permutations of string.ascii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` is the function you are looking for I believe

```
import string
import itertools
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

#as noted in an answer below you can pass repeat=2 for the same list
#but i want to leave this method in case someone comes across this and 
#needs to do it for two different lists
for x in itertools.product(letters, letters):
    print(f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
```

produces this output

```
aa
ab
ac
ad...
ba
bb
bc
bd ...
ca
cb
cc
cd...
da
db
dc
dd...
```

etc...

If you need it in a list then just do this `letters = [f'{x[0]}{x[1]}' for x in itertools.product(letters, letters)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. :)

```
import string
import itertools

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
length = 2

big_cartesian_product = list(itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=length))

print(big_cartesian_product)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of the built-ins `chr` and `ord`, one can quickly create a sequence of the letters to form strings from. Now, only a the product needs to be taken and combined to form strings.

```
letters = (chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1))
for s in map("".join, product(letters, repeat=2)):
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get all possible combinations of size `i` then iterate `i` from 1 to `set_length`. Here is a quick way to do so:

```
from itertools import combinations

set_legnth = 2
s = list(chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))
print([[''.join(x) for x in combinations(s, i)] for i in range(1, set_length+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one without python's itertools.

```
import string


alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def get_char_at(squence, n):
    return alphabet[ sequence // int(26** n) % 26]


n = 2
for sequence in range(26**n):
    result = ""
    for j in range(n):
        result += get_char_at(sequence, n-j-1)  
    print(result)
```